# find coordinates of a job number in one table and then find the numbers in matching coordinates in another table and sum those all up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have 2 different equally sized tables in excel. one table has job numbers, the other table has hours worked, i want to search how many hours in total were spent on each job

for example

```
------hours---------------job #
m t w th f s s     --- | ---   m t w th f s s
8 8 6 8  8 0 0     --- | ---   1 1 2 5  4 0 0
8 8 8 8  7 0 0     --- | ---   2 2 5 4  1 0 0
```

What would a formula look like to find the sum of hours spent working on job #5?
I import this data from google forms and I don't think I can change the format too much.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a simple `SUMIF`:

[image]

```
=SUMIF(I3:O4,B6,A3:G4)
```

Changing the value of B6 to 5 will yield 16 hours in B7.

Comment: This was so much easier than i was expecting, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified example using a smaller set of data:

[image]

Enter formula in C10 and fill down

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT too:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$Q$3=$I$7);$A$2:$G$3)
```